# A problem with counter

Tags: counter

I have PWM generator built on 74HC04BQ inverter. Pulse frequency is changed periodically by analog switch TS5A3153DCUR over 600 ms, frequency values are 44 kHz and 29 kHz. Binary ripple counter 74HC4020BQ divides this signal. The problem is the half of all boards has wrong output signal of counter. Output Q7 have to divide signal with 2^8 factor, and proper output frequency values should be 171 and 113 Hz. In fact, division factor could be 2^7 at one frequency, and 2^8 at another frequency, so values could be 171 and 226 Hz, 343 and 113 Hz, 343 and 226 Hz respectively.

I added a 10-kOhm resistor between invertor output and counter input on 3 boards, and the problem is not revealed more on these boards. I cannot make this modification on each board.

Having read the 74HC4020BQ datasheet I have not got understanding of an “input clamping current” parameter in table 4. In my opinion, wrong work appearing caused by high input current, but the current value measured by ampermeter is about 1 mA with power voltage 3.3V, and I think the counter input must have infinite resistance.

Please help me to get understanding of an “input clamping current” parameter, and why the problem can appear. 
[image]

Comment: [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) are you sure the input clamping current is your problem? I can't really see a problem description. You just say something's wrong, but not in which way. Please add actual/observed and expected behavior and oscilloscope  graphs where applicable. Please revise the question.

Comment: Whatever this circuit was supposed to *accomplish*, it is definitely the wrong approach for doing so.  You appear to be spending 3 ics to do a bad job of unstably generating two possible low frequencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, I'm not sure that input clamping current has much to do with this problem.

When setting the frequency by changing the RC timing capacitance with an analog switch without any kind of synchronization to the generated clock, you are probably generating some garbage on the clock during the transition from one frequency to another.

The 10K resistor along with the input capacitance on the CMOS gate is probably acting as a low pass filter and removing the glitchy clocks before they can mess up the counter.

Switching the resistance values instead of the capacitance values might be less glitchy, since when changing frequencies only the rate of change of the charge is modified,  not the actual capacitance and charge state.

Comment: Perhaps, though that is unlikely to explain a more than brief error.  The real issue is that the whole architecture of switching the components in an RC oscillator feeding a divider just isn't justified today.

Comment: I agree that there are many better ways to change the frequency